# hibernate error while using grails "POSTGRESQL-EXTENSIONS" json type

Tags: postgresql, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a **grails 3.3.10** application with a postgresql database and a table with a postgresql json type so I am using the POSTGRESQL-EXTENSIONS to create json types in my domain but a **exception is thrown when I try to define a json field.** **This is what I have done so far**:

I added the hibernate and postgresql dependenciens in my build.gradle:

```
classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.1.Final"

runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.6.jre7'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:postgresql-extensions:6.1.0'
```

and I added the custom dialect on my runtime.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    //the rest of the database config and credentials are skipped here
    dialect = 'net.kaleidos.hibernate.PostgresqlExtensionsDialect'
    }
```

And I also have modified the seq generation behaviour in my application.groovy:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
        id generator: 'org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator', params: [prefer_sequence_per_entity: true]
}
```

At this point, my gradle build works ok but when I am adding a custom json type to my domain class:

import net.kaleidos.hibernate.usertype.JsonMapType

```
class classWithJson {

    Map jsonField
    static constraints = {
    }
    static mapping = {
        data type: JsonMapType
    }
}
```

Now the build throws an Exception so it seems that I can't use the json custom type. the stackTrace is this one:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
        at grails.ui.console.GrailsSwingConsole.main(GrailsSwingConsole.groovy:90)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:928)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:805)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:206)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1265)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1336)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:3328)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3326)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3303)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:331)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:277)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:920)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToBoolean(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:198)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:87)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder$_closure1.doCall(HibernateMappingBuilder.groovy:457)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:947)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:930)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:181)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeClosure(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:587)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder.methodMissing(HibernateMappingBuilder.groovy:696)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:951)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1279)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1227)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:822)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateMappingBuilder.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:338)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:436)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder.evaluate(HibernateMappingBuilder.groovy:88)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder.evaluate(HibernateMappingBuilder.groovy)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.AbstractGormMappingFactory.evaluateWithContext(AbstractGormMappingFactory.java:108)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.AbstractGormMappingFactory.createMappedForm(AbstractGormMappingFactory.java:91)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContext$HibernateMappingFactory.createIdentityMapping(HibernateMappingContext.java:264)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.config.GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.getIdentityMapping(GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.java:928)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.config.JpaMappingConfigurationStrategy.getIdentityMapping(JpaMappingConfigurationStrategy.java:289)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractClassMapping.<init>(AbstractClassMapping.java:35)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernatePersistentEntity$1.<init>(HibernatePersistentEntity.java:35)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernatePersistentEntity.<init>(HibernatePersistentEntity.java:35)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(HibernateMappingContext.java:150)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntities(AbstractMappingContext.java:274)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContext.<init>(HibernateMappingContext.java:76)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.buildConfiguration(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:94)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:85)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:201)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 131 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Are you using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager`?

Comment: I am not using it but I also don't see that dependency on the plugin documentation:
https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/postgresql-extensions

@JeffScottBrown also, without the json type, hibernate is working fine. I already have created the database table and inserted data without using your dependency. I have all the hibernate libraries listed in the question

Comment: Which transaction manager are you using?

Comment: the transaction manager is not inside compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final"????

Comment: No, it isn't in `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final`.  `GrailsHibernateTransactionManager` is in `grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5` and that extends `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager`.

Comment: yes, I have the datastore dependency

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the creator of the plugin. A couple of things:

- I think the dialect configuration is not correct, it should be under the key `hibernate.dialect`. Please take a look at the configuration section in the docs: https://github.com/kaleidos/grails-postgresql-extensions/tree/6.x#configuration
- Version 6.1.0 of the plugin is for Grails 3 and Hibernate 5.2. I haven't tested it with Hibernate 5.1 but the Hibernate team introduced some breaking changes in 5.2. You should try to upgrade to Hibernate 5.2 and use Grails Postgresql Extensions 6.1.0 or Hibernate 5.1 and Grails Postgresql Extensions 5.3.0 that supports Hibernate 5.1.

The plugin contains a few test domain classes. Take a look at `TestMapJson` https://github.com/kaleidos/grails-postgresql-extensions/blob/6.x/grails-app/domain/test/json/TestMapJson.groovy.
I also recommend you to use JsonB instead of Json as it is more powerful and provides more operators and queries.